# Discrete Mathematics - If $A, B, C,$ and $D$ are sets, does it follow that $(A\oplus B)\oplus (C\oplus D) = (A\oplus D)\oplus (B\oplus C)$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

**If $A, B, C,$ and $D$ are sets, does it follow that $(A\oplus B)\oplus (C\oplus D) = (A\oplus D)\oplus (B\oplus C)$?**

I am totally stuck in proving this question using boolean algebra.

In order to prove using boolean algebra, I have to show that expansion of $(A\oplus B)\oplus (C\oplus D)$ is equal to $(A\oplus D)\oplus (B\oplus C)$.

So, I first expanded the left-hand side equation.

$(A\oplus D)\oplus (B\oplus C)$
$$=((A \oplus B) \land \overline{C}) \lor (\overline{(A\oplus B)} \land C)$$
$$= (((A \land \overline{B}) \lor (\overline{A} \land B)) \land \overline{C}) \lor(\overline{((A \land \overline{B}) \lor (\overline{A} \land B))} \land C)$$

But then I have no idea how to preceed to the next step. I can't see any parts that can be expanded.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Does $\oplus$ mean "exclusive or"?

Comment: How exactly are you supposed to prove this?  Do you have to apply pure algebra on these specific statements ... or can you use other, more general, mathematical proof techniques? If the latter, here's a Hint: first try and prove associativity and commutativity of the $\oplus$ operator in general.

Comment: Does ⊕ mean "exclusive or"? - Yes

Comment: Ok I will try to prove the associativity law of XOR.

Comment: Your “expansion” is wrong - it doesn’t have any D’s. Also, Boolean algebra usually uses multiplication/addition to simplify since it’s easier to understand, faster to write, and makes the distributive law obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a much simpler argument. The sets can be thought of as binary integers, where each possible element's presence within them corresponds with the value of a bit at the  corresponding with the element, and setwise operations replaced with bitwise ones. Bitwise XOR is commutative and associative, so too is setwise XOR (the symmetric difference).

Comment: Sorry... it's too complicated for me... I cannot understand

Comment: Commutative meaning that arguments of individual XOR instances can be swapped and associative means that the order of operations can be arbitrary, so brackets are able to be forgone entirely. With these two rules established, you can remove your expression's brackets, permute the arguments and re-add them as is needed to reach the resultant form.